# Python code running slow - code included - base64 encoding

Tags: python, base64

I am trying to base64 encode an audio flac file.

Sometimes my code times out. Sometimes it works. Any ideas on what am i doing wrong?

```
import base64
import urllib

def get_flac(uri=None):
   try:
       req = urllib.urlopen(uri)
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
   return req

def convert_base64(flac_file):
   audio_read = flac_file.read()
   return base64.b64encode(audio_read)

uri = None

try:
   the_file = get_flac('https://host123d1qv.cloudconvert.com/download/~_9IfzT78VnkmVoUPqux_1AQHm1w')
except Exception as e:
   print(e)

try:
   con = convert_base64(the_file)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

con
```

Comment: Have you tried running the same code with a FLAC file that you've already downloaded? At the moment, you're downloading the file each time you run the code, which is dependent on the speed of your Internet connection.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the exceptions you are seeing?

Comment: Im running the code in sandboxmode in Zapier Code. It times out after 10 seconds. https://zapier.com/help/code-python/

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
"2017-04-05T21:17:15.536Z 37f5f173-1a45-11e7-a3c6-690a7b270042 Task timed out after 10.00 seconds"